# How do I use snippets to get properties from the current class?

Tags: c#, reflection, code-snippets

Is it possible for me to create a snippet and have it analyze a current class, get the properties of said class, and then create a sql function that writes out line by line each property in a command parameter.

What I am looking for is doing something like this:

```
public static int Add(MyObject Message) {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MySqlConnection);
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Add_Message", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMFromUserID", Message.IMFromUserID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMToUserID", Message.IMToUserID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMMessage", Message.IMMessage);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMTimestamp", Message.IMTimestamp);
        connection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()) {
            Message.IMID = (int)reader["IMID"];
        }
        command.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
        return Message.IMID;
    }
```

Basically I want the snippet to populate the entire Add function and fill in the `@PropertyName` and the `Message.PropertyName` in the `command.Parameters.AddWithValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) are powerful enough. Maybe the [ReSharper's code templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) are powerful enough but I don't think so, too. You could look into using [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) if you really need or want code generation.

Personally I would suggest to avoid compiletime code generation altogether. You could use reflection - easy but slow - or runtime code generation - complex but fast. If performance is not a primary concern I suggest to use reflection.

```
 public static Int32 Add<TMessage>(TMessage message)
     where TMessage: IMessageWithIMID
 {
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand("Add_Message", connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // We look only at public instance properties but you can easily
        // change this and even use a custom attribute to control which
        // properties to include.
        var properties = typeof(TObject).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                       BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var parameterName = "@" + property.Name;

            var value = property.GetValue(message, null);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, value);
        }

        connection.Open();

        message.IMID = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();

        return message.IMID;
    }
}
```

Note that you have to introduce and implement the interface `IMessageWithIMID` in order to access the property `IMID`.

```
internal interface IMessageWithIMID
{
    Int32 IMID { get; set; }
}
```

Note that you also don't need a data read - you can just use [`ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar.aspx). This turns

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        message.IMID = (Int32)reader["IMID"];
    }
}
```

into

```
message.IMID = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

and you are done.

Comment: Oddly enough this will actually work well for me. I am looking to start building a base framework for the application and this would really help me get started. Essentially I wanted to have a template for CRUD but if I use generics then that should give me what I want.